# Peskin and Schroeder page 201, solving integral over angular part

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration

They make the following steps:
$$\int\frac{\Omega_\bf{k}}{4\pi}\ \frac{1}{(\hat{k}\cdot p')(\hat{k}\cdot p)} = \int_0^1d\xi\int\frac{\Omega_\bf{k}}{4\pi}\frac{1}{(\xi\ \hat{k}\cdot p'+(1-\xi)\ \hat{k}\cdot p)^2}=\int_0^1d\xi\frac{1}{(\xi\  p'+(1-\xi)\  p)^2}$$
In the first equality they use a Feynman parameter. I think the $0$ component of $\hat{k}$ equals 1.

How to get the second equality? Supposedly we can introduce a $d \cos(\theta)$, but the details are unclear for me since we have both $p$ and $p'$ which might not be parallel. (If we had only $p$, then we could align the $z$-axis with $p$.)

Comment: Hint: the denominator of the second integral has the form $(\hat{k} \cdot P)^2$.

Comment: @Hyperon, ofcourse, thanks!